# W32time on 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, ntp, w32time

Virtual server on MS 2016, on a domain, w32time is disabled. What is required so that time sync works with best practice to sync with domain DC?
Other MS 2012 R2 have w32time running but manual(triggered start).

Should it be automatic or manual? GPO required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If w32time is disabled the server will not time sync to the domain. The service should be set to automatic. All domain-joined servers/clients should time sync normally to the domain controller by default so no further configuration is necessarily required. If you want to maintain greater control over client time sync settings (e.g. sync using NTP) you can further customize using GPO:

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Windows Time Service\Time Providers